# What's this bug of maven3.3.9 while init opendaylight archetecture?

Tags: java, maven, opendaylight

I'm running this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype \
-DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/ \
-DarchetypeCatalog=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/archetype-catalog.xml
```

And I got this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: archetypeCatalog 'http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/archetype-catalog.xml' is not supported anymore. Please read the plugin documentation for details. -> [Help 1]
```

But I could open this link('http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/archetype-catalog.xml') on web.

After I remove last option as this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype \
-DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/
```

There is no error, but the result as bellow is not as expect as.

So how to use "-DarchetypeCatalog=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/archetype-catalog.xml" in maven?

Thank you~

Attach information:

```
gateway@gateway-20150605:~/workspace/toaster2$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-30-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Hope you have settings.xml configured correctly

Comment: Could you please paste your setting.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Configure your settings.xml as shown below, basically I added the ODL repo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">  
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>downloadSources</id>
            <properties>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>opendaylight-release</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>opendaylight-mirror</id>
                    <name>opendaylight-mirror</name>
                    <url>http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>opendaylight-mirror</id>
                    <name>opendaylight-mirror</name>
                    <url>http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>opendaylight-snapshots</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>opendaylight-snapshot</id>
                    <name>opendaylight-snapshot</name>
                    <url>http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>opendaylight-snapshot</id>
                    <name>opendaylight-snapshot</name>
                    <url>http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>maven-central-repo</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>cetral-repo</id>
                    <name>maven-central-repo</name>
                    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>cetral-repo</id>
                    <name>maven-central-repo</name>
                    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <!-- <activeProfile>maven-central-repo</activeProfile> -->
        <activeProfile>opendaylight-snapshots</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>opendaylight-release</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>downloadSources</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>maven-central-repo</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

And in archetypeCatalog you do not provide URL, you need to provide remote, local or internal, though its optional below is the updated mvn command. Check [here](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html#archetypeCatalog) for more on archetypeCatalog parameter

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.4.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype \
  -DarchetypeCatalog=remote \
  -DarchetypeVersion=<whatever your version is>
```

and adjust your `settings.xml` file to with a new `repository` named `archetypes`.
I found this when reading through the maven documentation. Sorry, but I don't the exact pointer at hand.

I fear the ODL community has not yet updated their `settings.xml` and we have to do it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the maven version when building the project, as following:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype \
-DarchetypeRepository=https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public \
-DarchetypeCatalog=https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/archetype-catalog.xml \
-DarchetypeVersion=1.2.2-Boron-SR2
```